# Select one row without duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

In mysql table `info` i have :

> Id , Name , City , date , status

I want to select all names from "info"
Making the query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id") 
         or die(mysql_error());

while ($raw = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
  $name = $raw["name"];
  echo ''.$name.'<br>';
}
```

Well, the result is that it returns all the entries.
I want to echo all the entries without duplicates.

Saying: under raw "name" we have inserted the name "John" 10 times.
I want to echo only one time.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id
```

The SQL keyword `DISTINCT` does the trick.

Answer (score 17):

try using this as your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id
```

to get distinct names

or as other suggested use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY id
```

I think the first one is more intuitive and there are no big performance difference between the two

**EDIT**

as the OP wants also the number of names here we go:

```
SELECT name,COUNT(id) AS n_names
FROM info WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

you can `ORDER BY` `name` or `n_names` depending on what you need

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id
```

to

```
SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY id
```

Observe that `GROUP BY` was added. More about group by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Edit:
for name with number of apparences try

```
SELECT name, count(name) FROM info WHERE status = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY id
```

Comment: works , but is i want to pun after the "name" the number of how many entryes are like this `code` echo ''.$name.' (times)';

Answer (score 1):

add `GROUP BY name` to your SQL Statment - this will only bring back one of each entry from the name column

Comment: When the GROUP By name is applied does it only take the first row? if the order by ID?

Comment: @YumYumYum the order is not guaranteed unless you add the `order by` statement

Comment: Thank therefore for safety i used this `SELECT id,duplicate_name,duplicate_email from SERVICE where duplicate_email='a@b.com' GROUP BY duplicate_email ORDER BY id`, which gives me the row when that user already signed up and next time login again on that particular project

Answer (score 0):

use 
    GROUP BY name 
statement

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY id") or      die(mysql_error());

while ($raw = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $name = $raw["name"];
                echo ''.$name.'<br>';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, returns the table names for a given database.

```
my $sql="select distinct table_name from COLUMNS  where table_schema='$database'"
my $sth = $dbht->prepare( $sql )
      or die "Cannot prepare SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";
  $sth->execute
      or die "Cannot execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";

  if ($DBI::err){

    $msg= "Data fetching terminated early by error: $DBI::errstr";

}


while (@col=$sth->fetchrow_array()){
    $table[$i]=$col[0];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that you are sending bulk sms and you don't want to send the same message  two times to the same guy John . What i discovered , is that using the trick of   GROUP BY  and ORDER BY at the same time works perfectly . But I don't say that its the best way . Here is how u can use it

```
SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY name
```

**EDIT:** This is important to note, when you need more then single column and there values are unique per row then the DISTINCT was not helping.

Comment: +1 this is CORRECT in my-case. Because i had to take `SELECT id,name,email from SIGNUP where groups='admin' Group by email ORDER by id`

Answer (score 0):

$sql="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM status =1 GROUP BY name ORDER BY name";

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
<?php while ( $fire=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<h4><?php echo $query['name']; ?><br></h4>
<?php } ?>
```