# Get rid of duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on mysql ,and I got some duplicate rows in a view. The view has simply image table data, and product data.
Now What I want is to get the only one column in the same id.
(I tried to make unique key but it's view so it couldn't work.)

Here is my query.

```
SELECT id, status_pub, name, code, 
       catch_copy, icon_new, icon_recommended, 
       u_date, order_num, st_time, ed_time, 
       isNULL(order_num) AS order_num_null, filename 
FROM TEST 
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT data_id 
             FROM R_CATEGORY 
             WHERE category_id REGEXP '^001') 
AND ((st_time IS NULL AND ed_time IS NULL) 
 OR (NOW() BETWEEN st_time AND ed_time) 
 OR (st_time IS NULL AND ed_time > NOW()) 
 OR (ed_time IS NULL AND st_time < NOW()) ) 
AND status_pub = 1     
ORDER BY order_num_null ASC, order_num ASC, u_date
```

Here you can see duplicate 3 duplicate 'id 48'. I want to retrieve the first one.
Such as 
    .
    .
46,
47,
48,
49,
.
.

NOT 
.
.
46,
47,
48,
48,
48,
49,

[image]

NOW I EDIT.
I added the DISTINCT STATEMENT,
But the result is 
[image: After adding distinct statement]

Comment: Have you tried `select distinct` in the outer query?

Comment: Yes, sir, I did it. But It didn't completely delete the duplicate rows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040631/select-one-row-without-duplicate-entries
This might help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove filename column which has different values for same id value and store the output in a temp table with filename column having null

Update this column in the temp table  later with top value from the view joining with id